# Creation of a java EE project on Eclipse for Java EE

Tags: eclipse, maven, java-ee-5

I have create a Java EE project using maven.

[Here is the generated hierarchy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SMipX.png)

If you observed on this image, I got an error in the index.jsp file.
When I focus in error, I got :
`The superclass "jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet" was not found on the Java Build Path`.

[Error message in index.jsp](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7lvhJ.png)

Can someone help me solve it? Thank you.

This is pom.xml file auto-generate.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>tn.ipsas.jee_eclipse</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven_jsf_wepp_app</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>

  <name>maven_jsf_wepp_app Maven Webapp</name>
  <!-- FIXME change it to the project's website -->
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.7</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.7</maven.compiler.target>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.11</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <finalName>maven_jsf_wepp_app</finalName>
    <pluginManagement><!-- lock down plugins versions to avoid using Maven defaults (may be moved to parent pom) -->
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.1.0</version>
        </plugin>
        <!-- see http://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/default-bindings.html#Plugin_bindings_for_war_packaging -->
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.8.0</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.22.1</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.2.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.5.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.8.2</version>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
  </build>
</project>
```

Comment: Something seems to be wrong at _Project > Properties: Java Build Path_. Since it's a Maven project, please show your `pom.xml` file.

Answer (score 0):

[Here is how I solved the problem.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JxYy2.png)
Right click on the project, **Property**> **Project Facets**
Selecting Dynamic Web Module and I upgraded the version to 3.1
Then **Apply**.

Comment: What was the value originally?

Comment: it was Dynamic Web Module with a lower version